# How to write a line of text into the middle of a file?

Tags: ruby, file

I have a command-line journaling application written in Ruby. I'd like the ability to back-date new entries and have the entries written to the file in chronological order. These are multi-line entries, so a simple sort after the fact isn't sufficient. I know how to append a line to the end of a text file:

```
def write(file, entry)
  open(file, 'r+') do |f|
    f.write entry
  end
end
```

However, let's say I have a variable called `line_number` that contains the position I want to start writing to. Is there a simple way to write `entry` into `file` starting at line number `line_number`, while preserving the original content?

For example, given a file with contents:

```
a
c
```

A call to the method `write_at(file, 2, 'b')` should yield:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: In term of coding, best would be to split, append, then merge?

Comment: I've considered that approach. Although these files aren't huge, I think it would mean storing all the lines in memory in an array or the like. I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way.

Comment: Can't help but a question, can you in ruby echo the shell, to get `sed` or `awk` printout?

Comment: That's an interesting thought. I am running this script on MacOS, so that's an option.

Comment: Is it really a requirement to not load the file into memory before writing? I think you should start with a simple approach and benchmark it.

Comment: You will have to rewrite files to insert content into the middle.  You can stream the first part, write the new data, then stream the remainder, but there is no way to do an in-place insert into an existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in doing this, if you are unable to load the entire file into memory, is that text files are sequential files that can be modified only at the end, as opposed to binary files that can be modified at any position in the file. If you could store the data in such a way that you could guarantee that all records would have equal byte lengths, then you could find the desired position and effectively shift everything after it by one record, and insert the desired record. Thus you would only have to rewrite part of the file. This is not commonly done these days, but it's possible.

If you were to use this binary storage format, then you could have a separate thing that formats it into log lines.

Even better would be to use a data base like SQLite; this would do the insertion and shifting for you (using a 'position' field).

Added 2018-02-08:

To be more precise, the issue is not technically whether the content of a file is text or binary, but rather whether or not the location of specified data can be easily calculated without reading the file from the beginning to find it. Unless text is in fixed length records, one cannot generally calculate the position of a text string without reading the file's content to find it.

Also, binary vs. text is a file open mode that (technically, if not practically) can be applied to any file, but a file must be opened in binary mode to reliably use file seek commands. For operating systems that convert new lines to multiple characters (I believe Windows still converts them to "\r\n"), the binary mode will see the two character string as two bytes and not as one character.